# Offset difficulties with Images on Planes and Greenscreen/Transparent movie

Tags: add-on

I need to tweak the beginning time of a greenscreen image in "Images on Planes". It's a conductor who I filmed in front of a greenscreen in order to create one of those "virtual choir" videos. He is off a frame or two from a timpani hit, and I am having lots of problems adjusting the frames.

First off, after I make an adjustment with offset, I have to close and restart the program, or there will be a weird "bump", or "gap" in the movie.

Second, he may be only one frame late, so, I adjust the offset by one frame, and the next time I open it, he is about five or six frames ahead.

This seems to only be a problem with the movie I created with the "alpha" codec. Other "Image on Planes" videos that are used in the video that are not dealing with the greenscreen seem to be behaving fine.

Comment: The quickest way is to export video as Image Sequence (like PNG) ... in that way you can confirm if the issue is codec in your case.

Comment: Yes. Using an Image Sequence solved my problem! There probably is something weird going on with the QT Animation codec and Images with Planes, as I could never line up my videos, whereas, once I used the Image Sequence of the same project there were no problems.